# Exception handling with and MVC application

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, exception

I'm in my early days of programming and have one a few applications in Java and C#. I'm using a basic mvc-logic with a desk top application as view, a controller and models connected to a database.

I've spent quite a few brain cells on how to handle exceptions in a good looking way and so far my solutions kind of smells. For a while I threw all the exceptions to the view, but this seems sucky. Now I have catch-blocks in the controller, but have no idea what to do with them.

If the controller used to have void-methods, they now return a string with some kind of error message. If the methods has to return something, they now return null and the view checks if the response is null before doing anything.

What I'm looking for is a better looking solution! Is there a best practice way to do this? I haven't found anything during googleing.

I realize this is a sort of general question, but I'm hoping for some tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this other Question and related answers could help:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10293950/1158895